# mobile application development( not for android)

Tags: java, mobile

I am intrested in mobile application development in java but can't find any tutorial
my doubts are
which is the best tutorial in web on this ?
and what all thing i require [i have  javase now]

Comment: What is your targeted platform ? Are you planning to do J2ME ?

Comment: yeah i am targeting at j2me which work on midp 2.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here it is,

http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-05-2005/jw-0502-midlet.html
http://www.digilife.be/quickreferences/pt/j2me%20step%20by%20step.pdf